# Background Color on Mobile Chrome and WebView not displaying properly

Tags: android, html, css, mobile

I have an Android tablet (**Lenovo Tab 4 10 Plus** (TB-X704L)) that is running Chrome 72, and a WebView app that uses latest Chromium.

On both the Chrome browser and the WebView app, the background `linear-gradient` colours are strangely messed up.

This is what it looks like on every other device, including Chrome 72 on desktop.

[image: normal view]

And this is what it looks like on the tablet

[image: tablet view]

As shown, the first button is taking the colors of the second button for some reason.

Similarly, on desktop and other tablets:
[image: normal view 1]

versus on the Lenovo 4:
[image: tablet view 1]

This is the CSS of the circular buttons (first button for example):

```
background: rgb(221, 221, 221) 
            linear-gradient(rgb(135, 138, 209), rgb(91, 94, 148)) 
            repeat scroll 0% 0% / 100% padding-box padding-box
```

I have not yet run into this issue on any other tablets, so I'm wondering if this is isolated to this particular tablet. What's more puzzling is that Firefox on the same device shows the correct colors.

Things I've tried to no avail:

1. Checked for color settings within Accessibility to see if something akin to color-blind mode was enabled. It was not.
2. Going to `chrome://flags` >> `Force color profile` and trying every color profile.
3. Changing the `rgb(rrr,ggg,bbb)` to hex codes.
4. Factory reset.

Any idea what could be causing this strange issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a million different things, finally figured it out!

Originally, the buttons were created using

`background-image: linear-gradient(...)`

But, when I changed it to

`background: linear-gradient(...)`

everything was magically rendering properly.

I'm really curious to know what could have caused this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you: I read in another forum that changing the `rgb(rrr,ggg,bbb)` to `rgba(rrr,ggg,bbb)` did the trick.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's difficult to tell what is being asked here, and this question cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. Please provide the context, and/or post code samples of what you have done (i.e.: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com))